# To run jar file exist in target folder from batch file and shell script

Tags: java, windows, shell, maven, batch-file

I am creating build for a test maven project that have myserver.bat, myworker.bat, myui.jar files that will be created after building my project. My requirement is to run the project automatically with one 'install.sh' that will check environment before running the project, then it will run myserver.bat, myworker.bat and myui.jar to run project.

myui.jar is created inside 'ui\target' folder, if I run command :

> java -jar myui.jar

from 'ui\target' folder then it show resource not found error. But if I run it like this :

> java -jar "target\myui.jar"

Then it run project correctly.

So I have created one bat file named **myui.bat** that contains command : `java -jar "target\myui.jar"`

I have to write all command into install.sh file for automate run.

**install.sh** contains

```
start 'myproject\bin\myserver.bat' myserver.yml
start 'myproject\bin\myworker.bat' myworker.yml
start 'ui\myui.bat'
```

It launch server and worker correctly, but for ui, it do nothing as the command is now :
..mypath/ui>start java -jar "target\myui.jar" which is incorrect.

And if I directly write :

```
 start 'myproject\bin\myserver.bat' myserver.yml
 start 'myproject\bin\myworker.bat' myworker.yml
 java -jar "ui\target\myui.jar"
```

Then it throw runtime error for resources not found.

How can I run install.sh to run my maven project?

Comment: You work on a *ix or a windows plattform?

Comment: But *.sh files are shell commands not windows batch?!

Comment: Yes, I know, finally this sh will run on Linux, I just need command o run jar file from target folder.

Comment: Can you Show the error message?

Comment: @Jens It throwing java,lang.RuntimeException error.

Comment: Then add the stacktrace to your question

Comment: @Jens the error was because my jar is unable to get resources that are required to run myui, and I have told that java -jar "target\myui.jar" from ui folder working fine. I need either command directly in install.sh or from another bat file that have this command.

Answer (score 1):

I got one solution that writing these, get into ui then running command like :

```
start 'myproject\bin\myserver.bat' myserver.yml
start 'myproject\bin\myworker.bat' myworker.yml
cd ui
java -jar "target\myui.jar"
```